# ASRI frequencies database for FBOs

Tags: fcc

Is there a database of ASRI frequencies anywhere? I've been looking, but can't find anything. I know there is an [FCC database](https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/searchGeographic.jsp) of frequencies, but all the frequencies ASRI applies for are under their own name, so it's not easy to figure out the business they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aviation Spectrum Resources, Inc. (ASRI) is the spectrum manager for aeronautical "company frequencies" (128.825-132.0 and 136.5-136.975). ASRI licenses all the frequencies with the FCC and assigns them to other users, so unfortunately the FCC data only provides part of the story but it is a start. The primary users of these frequencies are airlines but they are also used by Fixed Base Operators (FBOs), corporate aviation bases, some medevac services, and other entities.

---

[Finding Air Traffic Frequencies](https://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/Finding_Air_Traffic_Frequencies)

---

[Database of Frequency Allocations](http://www.grss-ieee.org/frequency_allocations.html)

### [image]